# Python/SQL: using a list variable as a regular expression in REGEXP_EXTRACT

Tags: python, sql, regex

I have a file with many repeated regular expressions that are used in the REGEXP_EXTRACT function within a SQL statement.

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(log_1, "(.*) (H.*)")
REGEXP_EXTRACT(log_2, "(.*) (H.*)")
```

To reduce redundancy, I created a list that has all of the regular expressions.

```
regexps = ['(.*) (H.*)']
```

Then, I replace regular expressions within the file with a variable:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(log_1, regexps[0])
REGEXP_EXTRACT(log_2, regexps[0])
```

The error I get:

```
Invalid table alias or column reference 'regexps'
```

Is it not allowed to replace a regular expression with a variable inside of REGEXP_EXTRACT()?

Comment: Please show the full traceback. I think something is missing here. At the very least, I have no idea why you need to put your string in a list with `regexps = ['(.*) (H.*)']`

Comment: So many regular expressions repeated many times in the file and I want to reduce redundancy by storing them in a list and using the variable names instead of having the regular expressions themselves retyped. Does that make sense?

Comment: I don't have a full traceback; that is the only error message I get after running the script. Thanks

Comment: If store them in a dictionary but anyway, the error doesn't make sense to me from what you've shown. Please edit in the traceback. The list index should still only pass a string literal as an argument.

Comment: It can't be. If you have this inside an `except Exception as e: print(e)` then either remove the try/except or `import traceback` and use `except Exception: print(traceback.format_exc())`

Comment: "If store them in a dictionary"
Are you suggesting to use a dictionary instead of a list?
    "The list index should still only pass a string literal as an 
    argument. "
What does this mean?

Comment: It's not worth continuing the discussion unless you give a traceback. I'm happy to explain those comments if you give us an avenue to move forwards; the error doesn't make sense to me currently without this extra information.

Comment: ok, not sure how to generate that, but i'll try

Comment: I explained in an earlier comment

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @jellywu this is hive, right?

Comment: Could you provide a minimum working example - i.e. the smallest amount of code which will reproduce the problem without people needed access to other things?